# play video when text is recognized AR

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, vuforia, text-recognition

I am trying to develop an android app via vuforia sdk and unity.
The app should:
detect a string and as soon as the string is detected, will play video on video prefabs (not full screen). 
However, I could not figure out where in TextEventHandler.cs is handling whether text is detected...

Sorry guys.. i forgot to post code..
below was what I found in TextEventHandler that vuforia provides to me... 
I was guessing maybe this is handling whether the text is detected or not

```
// Once the text tracker has initialized and every time the video background changed,
        // set the region of interest
        if (mVideoBackgroundChanged)
        {
            TextTracker textTracker = TrackerManager.Instance.GetTracker<TextTracker>();
            if (textTracker != null)
            {
                CalculateLoupeRegion();
                textTracker.SetRegionOfInterest(mDetectionAndTrackingRect, mDetectionAndTrackingRect);
                //v.SetActive (true);
            }
            mVideoBackgroundChanged = false;
        }
```

Comment: You didn't post any code, so we have no idea either

Comment: Sorry.. I forgot to post codes -_-. I was so helpless on this one

Answer (score 0):

Use Text Recognition instead of this method. Visit [here](https://youtu.be/YCxZfl9Rbgg) to see how to recognize text. And load your video when the text is recognized instead.